Can you ID this Cambodian rural ghost story?
I'm looking for a film that came out about five years ago and was, I thought, Cambodian, though many failed searches make me think I could be wrong.
It was critically-acclaimed and set on a rural farm where an elderly widow (or widower) and their family were dealing with the loss of their aged relative. 
It wasn't a ghost story in the traditional sense, there was no suspense. However, this lost relative would sometimes fade in and simply sit with family at the outdoor dinner table or family room in long, almost hypnotic takes.  The mood was Tarkovsky meets Elegy.  I remember someone in the film had kidney problems or something.  The movie made quite an emotional impact.

This is Uncle Boonmee Who Can Recall His Past Lives (2010), which is not a Cambodian but a Thai film.

Suffering from acute kidney failure, Uncle Boonmee has chosen to spend
  his final days surrounded by his loved ones in the countryside.
  Surprisingly, the ghost of his deceased wife appears to care for him,
  and his long lost son returns home in a non-human form. Contemplating
  the reasons for his illness, Boonmee treks through the jungle with his
  family to a mysterious hilltop cave - the birthplace of his first
  life.

It won the Palme d'Or at Cannes, and numerous other awards.

That's it!  Thank you for ending a five-year search -- MUCH appreciated!

You are welcome.

@Filmfan If you may, please accept the answer! :)
